# Php. Adding new column to an array, but is doubling up the results

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is to add a new column into the array so I can put these 2 columns into it:

uuid1 . '-' . uuid2

What it is doing is that it is doubling up the results like:

```
$base = \Query::Create()
                ->Database('main')
                ->Select(
                        'devices.id',
                        'devices.uuid1',
                        'devices.uuid2')
                ->From('devices')
                ->where(column('deleted_on'), is, new \DBNull())
                ->limit(5);

try {
    $MySqlItems = $base->Execute();

    foreach ($MySqlItems as $list_item) {
        $list_item['result'] = "";
        array_push($MySqlItems, $list_item);
    }
} catch(\Exception $ex) {}
```

From another page:

```
$response['MySql'] = $MySqlData;
```

Results:

```
"MySql": [
        {
            "id": "64",
            "uuid1": "1318",
            "uuid2": "52366"
        },
        {
            "id": "296",
            "uuid1": "17304",
            "uuid2": "10994"
        },
        {
            "id": "445",
            "uuid1": "17488",
            "uuid2": "57404"
        },
        {
            "id": "64",
            "uuid1": "1318",
            "uuid2": "52366",
            "result": "1318-52366"      What I want the result to be like.
        },
        {
            "id": "296",
            "uuid1": "17304",
            "uuid2": "10994",
            "result":
        },
        {
            "id": "445",
            "uuid1": "17488",
            "uuid2": "57404",
            "result":
        }       
]
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: you can use concat function in query.

Comment: Do you have any samples so I can reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple PHP concatenation would suffice, and use a reference on `$list_item` to update that occurance on the fly. So note the `&` on `as &$list_item`

```
foreach ($MySqlItems as &$list_item) {
    $list_item['result'] = $list_item['uuid1'] . '-' . $list_item['uuid2'];
}
```

If you want to remove the `uuid` fields as well do

```
foreach ($MySqlItems as &$list_item) {
    $list_item['result'] = $list_item['uuid1'] . '-' . $list_item['uuid2'];
    unset( $list_item['uuid1'], $list_item['uuid2']);
}
```

Comment: When I added this into the foreach loop. I still get the doubling.  Instead of 5 I get 10.

Comment: Woops, my mistake, try the new answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your mysql, you will get the idea for your problem

```
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100));
insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
select id, title, concat(id, '-', title)result from Test;
```